# Return value if method parameter is NULL else don't return

Tags: c#, .net

I understand that there are some different methods to using an object if it is null.

My question is a bit different though.
Maybe I'm just not thinking it through and there might be an existing solution.

I want to check if a variable is null.
If so, return a specific value from the method.
If it isn't null, continue with processing of the method.

And I need to do the null checks at different locations in the method.  Some of my code might have three or four input parameters that need to checked.
So i couldn't use `if (parameter1 == null || parameter2 == null)`.

What is the best way to do that considering the below example? 
I'm basically trying to reduce the amount of code required.

```
public List<OutputClass> GetOutputs(InputClass input1, OtherInputClass input2)
{
     if (input == null)
     {
          return new List<OutputClass>();
     }

     // continue with processing
     // do something with input1

     if (input2 == null)
     {
          return new List<OutputClass>();
     }

     // continue with processing
     // do something with input2

     var outputs = //some processing using the input data;

     return outputs;
}
```

Comment: That looks like the best way to do it. What is the problem?

Comment: IMHO there's no better way

Comment: The only "replacement" for if statements is a Switch, which would not work in this example. Structure your if statements correctly and this is entirely possible.

Comment: If *"some of [your] code might have three or four input parameters that need to [be] checked"*, then your question's example should reflect that scenario and not a scenario where you only have one input.

Comment: @RufusL yea that is what I was thinking as well, but I wanted to ask the community.  The only "issue" per say is that I could end up having these if statements like 4 or 5 times in the method and it could get in the way of the actual important code.

Comment: @IssaFram Then structure your class accordingly. Instead of putting the ifs in the main function, break up each scenario into its own function and return a bool.

Comment: @JonnyHenly ok. I've updated the code.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @BrandonMiller that is understandable.  I can definitely refactor my code.  I'll keep that in mind if there are no solutions to this issue for a quick fix.

Comment: My only comment on your above example is that if you plan on returning an empty list if any of the arguments is null, then do all that validation up front. In your sample code, you have a comment between null checks that says, *"// continue with processing // do something with input1"*. That's a waste of processing time if `input2 == null`.

Comment: @RufusL the processing I mentioned work a bit differently. But this goes along with the suggestion that **BrandonMiller** made.  Maybe I just need some refactoring.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it needs some refactoring. `GetOutputs` should do just one thing - return a list of `OutputClass` based on the provided inputs. If it does some other processing based on one or more of the arguments that affect the overall program state, then it sounds like a code smell and that additional processing should probably be factored out into a different method. Note that your example does not describe what you mean by *"the processing I mentioned work a bit differently"*, which makes it hard to give a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Given your example code, where you return a new list if either argument is null, I would propose that you do all the argument validation up front so you don't waste any processing time doing things that will just be thrown away if a later argument check returns is null:

```
public List<OutputClass> GetOutputs(InputClass input1, OtherInputClass input2)
{
    var outputs = new List<OutputClass>();

    if (input1 == null || input2 == null)
    {
        return outputs;
    }

    // continue with processing
    // do something with input1
    OutputClass output1 = GetOutput(input1.SomeValue);

    // do something with input2
    OutputClass output2 = GetOutput(new CustomClass(input2.AnotherValue));

    // create outputs based on the input data
    outputs.Add(output1);
    outputs.Add(output2);

    return outputs;
}
```

If the processing needed between validation of `input1` and `input2` makes some change to the program state, then you may need some additional refactoring. In general, methods should be made as discreet as possible, where they only do one thing. You have to be careful of side effects. From the client point of view, they get the same return value if either or both of the arguments is null. The general expectation would be that the state of the program would also remain the same in those 3 cases.

This is a general recommendation, however; if you gave a more specific example of what you're doing, it would possibly lead to a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I generally make use of private helper functions in the scenario you're describing, though it ultimately depends on the situation.

For example:

```
public List<OutputClass> GetOutputs(InputClass inputOne, OtherInputClass inputTwo) {
     List<OutputClass> allTogether;

     // do something with inputOne
     allTogether = GetOutputsHelperOne(inputOne);

     // do something with inputTwo       
     allTogether = GetOutputsHelperTwo(inputTwo, allTogether);

     var outputs = // some processing using 'allTogether'

     return outputs; // or just return 'allTogether'
}

/*
 * Do something with inputOne
 */
private List<OutputClass> GetOutputsHelperOne(InputClass inputOne) {
    List<OutputClass> tmp = new List<OutputClass>();

    if (inputOne == null) {
          return tmp;
    }

    // else do something to 'tmp' with 'inputOne'
    return tmp;
}

/*
 * Do something with inputTwo
 */
private List<OutputClass> GetOutputsHelperTwo(OtherInputClass inputTwo, List<OutputClass> allTogether) {
    List<OutputClass> tmp = new List<OutputClass>();

    if (inputTwo == null) {
          return allTogether;
    }

    // else do something to 'tmp' with 'inputTwo'
    // or just manipulate 'allTogether' with 'inputTwo'

    // then merge 'tmp' with 'allTogether'
    // or just return 'allTogether'

    return allTogether;
}
```

Sorry if the above syntax is incorrect, I don't program in `C#`, just take it as pseudo code.